# How to properly add a related record

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I have a collection of comments and a collection of posts.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource("posts", {
    path: "/posts"
  });
  this.resource("post", {
    path: "/:post_id"
  }, function () {
    this.resource("comments", {
      path: "/comments"
    });
  });
});
App.Post = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: attr(),
  name: attr(),
  comments: Ember.hasMany("App.Comment", {
    key: 'comments'
  })
  if embedded = comments: Ember.hasMany("App.Comment", {
    key: 'comments',
    embedded: true
  })
});
App.Post.url = "/posts";
App.Comment = Ember.Model.extend({
  id: attr(),
  message: attr(),
  post: Ember.belongsTo('App.Post', {
    key: 'post'
  })
});
```

How can I either:

1. Create a new embedded comment.
2. Create a non-embedded comment and have that creation add the `comment_id` into `comment_ids: []` on the Post model.

I can get the `post_id` to enter into the comments if non-embedded, but am having difficulty getting the `comment_id` added into the post.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `create()` method.

```
// get a post instance to insert a new comment to.
var post = App.Post.create(); // or App.Post.find()

// insert a new comment.
var comment = post.get('comments').create();
comment.message = "Test Poster";

// since you are using embedded relationship,
// no need to save the comment, just save the post.
post.save();
```

If you are using non-embedded comment, change your relationship to `{ embedded: false }`, just don't forget to call save on your comment.

```
// if non-embedded
comment.save();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `push` the new `comment` into the `comments` collection on the `post`.

```
var post = this.get('post');
var comments = post.get('comments');
comments.pushObject(comment);
comment.save();
post.save();
```

Here's a JSBin with the general idea : http://jsbin.com/OnUXEti/12/edit

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! I am using ember-model right now, so I'll change some things around and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: this would force a 2nd, unnecessary json request though. when pushing clean object, it shouldnt mark the parent record as dirty

Answer (score 0):

in case this helps anyone -- i put in pull request on ember-model that fixes issue [pull request diff on github](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/pull/291/files)